# DB2 for IBM i (iSeries) Date - Need to Compare (Current Date - 1)

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am new to DB2 for IBM i (iSeries) syntax. I would like to compare a date field in a table to   yesterday's date (current date - 1) for auditing purposes. However, I cannot get   it to work. I receive a "[SQL0182] A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid" error. Any help is greatly appreciated. See code below.

```
SELECT DECIMAL_FIELD
 FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
  WHERE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(DIGITS(DECIMAL_FIELD), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')) > DATE(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_ISO(CURRENT DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - 1
AND DECIMAL_FIELD <> 0
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Is there an error message that you can provide?

Comment: Yes, I get "[SQL0182] A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid." when I add the "- 1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the duration.

```
SELECT DECIMAL_FIELD
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(DIGITS(DECIMAL_FIELD), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')) >
    DATE(VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_ISO(CURRENT DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - 1 DAY
    AND DECIMAL_FIELD <> 0
```

Also the comparison can be simplified:

```
SELECT DECIMAL_FIELD
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(DIGITS(DECIMAL_FIELD), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')) >
    CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY
    AND DECIMAL_FIELD <> 0
```

[Datetime arithmetic in SQL](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdatetimearith.htm?lang=en-us)

Comment: @Toya - of course, in the interest of being able to use an index over `DECIMAL_FIELD` (which is a **terrible** name for something date-related...), it'd be better to do the transform the other way, and construct a comparable value from `CURRENT_DATE` instead.  That, and use an inclusive lower bound.

Comment: The following revision to the above query defines an expression that serves as an effective-literal, a _constructed_ value typed compatible as a comparison value for the greater-than predicate with the 'DECIMAL_FIELD' column, thus allowing for use of a non-derived INDEX on that column: SELECT DECIMAL_FIELD
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE DECIMAL_FIELD >
              DECIMAL(   VARCHAR_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP_ISO(CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY), 'YYYYMMDD'), 8 ) /* decimal casting scalar used to match type\len of DECIMAL_FIELD */
    AND DECIMAL_FIELD <> 0